# Organising csv. file data in Python

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, python-3.7, data-analysis

I am quite a beginner with Python but I have a programming-related project to work on, so, I really would like to ask some help. I didn´t find many simple solutions to organize the data such a way that I could do some analysis with that.
First, I have multiple csv-files, which I read in as DataFrame objects. In the end, I need them all to analyze together (right now the files are separated to the list of DataFrames but later on I probably will need those as one DataFrame object).
However, I have a problem with organizing and separating the data. These are thousands of rows in one column, a part of it is presented:

```
                                            CIP;Date;Hour;Cons;REAL/ESTIMATED
EN025140855608477018TC2L;11/03/2020;1;0                                 057;R
EN025140855608477018TC2L;11/03/2020;2;0                                 078;R
EN025140855608477018TC2L;11/03/2020;3;0                                 033;R
EN025140855608477018TC2L;11/03/2020;4;0                                 085;R
EN025140855608477018TC2L;11/03/2020;5;0                                 019;R
                                                                    ...
EN025140855608477018TC2L;11/04/2020;20;0                                786;R
EN025140855608477018TC2L;11/04/2020;21;0                                288;R
EN025140855608477018TC2L;11/04/2020;22;0                                198;R
EN025140855608477018TC2L;11/04/2020;23;0                                728;R
EN025140855608477018TC2L;11/04/2020;24;0                                275;R
```

The area, where the huge space between, the number should be merged together, for example, `0.057`, which information represents "Cons" (actually it is the most important information). 
I should be able to split data into 5 columns in order to proceed with the analysis. However, it should be a universal tool for different csv-files without knowing the including symbols. But the structure of the content and the heading is always the same.

I would be happy if anyone might know to recommend a way to work with this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are trying to do is convert the `Cons` column so that the spaces become a dot.

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep=";")
df['Cons'] = df['Cons'].str.replace("\s+",".")
df['Cons'].head()
```

Output:

```
0    0.057
1    0.078
2    0.033
3    0.085
4    0.019
```